# Call (Report-)Function from Class Method to change screen title

Tags: class, abap, title, dynpro

I wanna change my titlebar in a dynpro when a specific class method is triggered. So I thought I could call a function in my report, where my dynpro is located, which changes uses the 'SET TITLE' to change the titlebar content.

Is this possible and how exactly? Or is there even a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Why? What is the business reason behind this? The answer depends on the actual reason for this...

Comment: Custom class or standard? What report it is?

Comment: My colleauge made a report (runnable program) which is calling all of its methods from a class. It should become a software for a counter. But it's just a practice by now.

For example if someone paid his stuff the titlebar should get a new number for a new customer.

So the problem is, that in the actual report nothing really happens but calling methods. And I don't know how to change the titlebar from a class method.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SET TITLEBAR`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/de/abapset_titlebar_dynpro.htm) during the PBO processing - it doesn't matter if it is used from a method, a FORM or the module directly. I'd recommend having one single `SET TITLEBAR` statement that is always called at the same point in the control flow instead of littering the code with `SET TITLEBAR` statements for better maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I needed to implement something similar so I defined a class hierarchy where I created an abstract class with a method 'CALL_DYNPRO'. This method is intended to load an specific dynpro in the concrete classes.

So, depending on an action I defined internally I generate the appropriate instance and then the method 'CALL_DYNPRO' loads the dynpro I created with their own gui statuses and titles.

The following is more or less the code I created.

```
********************************* The abstract class
class lc_caller definition abstract.
  public section.
    methods: call_dynpro.
endclass.

class lc_caller implementation.
  method call_dynpro.
  endmethod.
endclass.

********************************* The concrete classes
class lc_caller_01 definition inheriting from lc_caller.
  public section.
    methods: call_dynpro redefinition.
endclass.

class lc_caller_01 implementation.
  method call_dynpro.
    call screen 101.
  endmethod.
endclass.

class lc_caller_02 definition inheriting from lc_caller.
  public section.
    methods: call_dynpro redefinition.
endclass.

class lc_caller_02 implementation.
  method call_dynpro.
    call screen 102.
  endmethod.
endclass.

********************************* Factory    
class caller definition.
  public section.
  class-methods call importing i_type type char01 
                returning value(r_instance) type ref to lc_caller.
endclass.

class caller implementation.
  method call.
    data: caller1 type ref to lc_caller_01,
          caller2 type ref to lc_caller_02.
    case i_type.
      when '0'.
        create object caller1.
        r_instance = caller1.
      when '1'.
        create object caller2.
        r_instance = caller2.
      when others.
    endcase.
  endmethod.
endclass.

start-of-selection.
data obj type ref to lc_caller.
obj = caller=>call( '0' ).
obj->call_dynpro( ).
```

This is the code inside the PBOs.

Dynpro 101

```
module status_0101 output.
  set pf-status 'FORM1'.
  set titlebar 'VER'.
endmodule.
```

Dynpro 102

```
module status_0102 output.
  set pf-status 'FORM2'.
  set titlebar 'TRA'.
endmodule.
```

If tomorrow I need to call another dynpro I create it and then code the concrete class to load it.

Very straightforward and works very nice.

Hope it helps.